# guide me turn this block of pseudo code into javascript code

Tags: javascript

I have a block of pseudo code that needs deciphering and I feel like I am on the right track:

Pseudo Code:

```
//initialize constant variable median=0.
//Sort the list as list.sort()
//Find the length of list as listlength=list.length
//if listlength is odd{
// find the middle number middle as Math.round(listlength-1)
// Now median=list[middle-1]
//} 
//else{
// middle=list.length/2
// median=(list[middle]+list[middle-1])/2 
//}
//print median on console using console.log(median)
```

Please keep in mind that the above is pseudo code! It needs to be deciphered and turned into Javascript! I'm posting what I have so far as I am stuck right now! Any help with this, a point in the right direction would be great

My code so far:

Javascript:

```
var median = 0;
var sortList = list.sort(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11);
if list.length =
```

After this I have no idea what else to do. Am I even on the right track? Thanks in advanced. This is pseudo code that someone else wrote, I did not write it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it only asks others to do OPs homework.

Answer (score 1):

Hi the code will be something like this:

```
<script>
        var median = 0;
        var middle;
        var list = [4,3,2,1,5,6];
        var listlength = list.length;
        list.sort();

        //if listlength even find the middle element

        if (listlength%2 !== 0){
           middle =  Math.round(listlength-1);
           median = list[middle-1]; 
           // In my opinion should be 
           // middle =  Math.round((listlength-1)/2);
           // median = list[middle];


        }
        //if listlength is even find the arithmetic mean of 2 middle elements.
        else{
           middle = listlength/2;
           median = (list[middle]+list[middle-1])/2;
        }
        console.log(median);
    </script>
```

But i think algorithm to find median for odd numbers is wrong. When listlength is odd, its just enough to print middle element of the list(If array is sorted ofc).

Answer (score 0):

Convert it into steps

```
//initialize constant variable median=0. Step 1
//Sort the list as list.sort() Step 2
//Find the length of list as listlength=list.length
//if listlength is odd{ Step 3
// find the middle number middle as Math.round(listlength-1) Step 4
// Now median=list[middle-1] 
//} 
//else{
// middle=list.length/2
// median=(list[middle]+list[middle-1])/2 
//}
//print median on console using console.log(median) Step 5
```

Then you can easily convert it into JavaScript

I don't know which language above was, maybe a human readable algorithm. But it would be

```
var median = 0; // Step 1
var list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
list.sort(); // would execute on an Array only
if((list.length) % 2 == 0) { // Step 2 and 3
   // even list
   // do the even function to get median Step 4
} else {
   // odd list
   // do the odd function to get the median
}
document.write(median); // write the median! Step 5
```

I really think you need to learn the JavaScript syntax! :) It would further guide you how JavaScript works.

For sort method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: I too really think you need to learn javascript syntax. Arrays are declared in `[]` and objects in `{}` and your code won't work `:(`

Comment: I am not even intermediate in JavaScript! :) I just tried to convert his code :) you can edit my post where the Arrays are getting errors..

Comment: I commented that because you've have included that line "*I really think you need to learn the javascript syntax! :)*"

Comment: Oh that part you meant? :O I am sorry! I thought you mean `var[]` like thing! :D I knew that thing. :) Sorry for confusion brother.